# Help me stop this code smelling so much?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I wrote a class for interacting with the [amazon-ecs gem](https://github.com/jugend/amazon-ecs) which looks like this:

```
# app/models/aws.rb
require "amazon/ecs"
class Aws

  # various methods such as...
  def lookup(item_id, options = { :id_type => "ean" # etc... })
    Amazon::Ecs.item_lookup(item_id, options)
  end
end
```

Now I suspect that a few things are smelly about the way I've implemented this so I have some noob questions...

1. How do I make it so that I don't have to "require amazon/ecs" at the top? I have the gem included in my Gemfile.
2. How do I make it so that I don't have to prefix all gem method calls with "Amazon::Ecs"? I tried putting "include Amazon::Ecs" at the top just after I open the class but that threw an error?
3. A class isn't the best way to do this is it? I get the sense that it doesn't make sense that I have to do

   aws = Aws.new
   aws.lookup(an_item_id)

whenever I want to access the class's methods. Should I use a module instead? How do I do that?

Comment: You have several questions but I only know the answer to one. That is preventing me from answering any. It may be best to split up your questions in case anyone is feeling the same way. -- For question 1, adding gem 'amazon/ecs' to your gemfile, doing a bundle install and restarting your server will allow you to ditch that line.

Comment: ha! I actually had it in my Gemfile all along so I could have just removed it. I've no idea why I thought I couldn't. I probably tried before and forgot to restart the server or something. I would split them up but I don't want to clutter up the questions list with 3 questions about the same piece of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. justinxreese already answered this for you -- just include the line `gem 'amazon/ecs'` in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.
2. I don't know if this is common practice, but I would avoid trying to mixin `Amazon::Ecs`. I think the prefix helps readers easily differentiate what is your code and what is Ecs code.
3. A class is fine in this case, but instead of defining each method as an instance method, make them class methods instead.

Example:

```
def self.lookup(item_id, options = { :id_type => "ean" # etc... })
    Amazon::Ecs.item_lookup(item_id, options)
end
```

**or**

```
def Aws.lookup(item_id, options = { :id_type => "ean" # etc... })
    Amazon::Ecs.item_lookup(item_id, options)
end
```

Whatever fits your preference.

Now you can call this method without instantiating a new Aws object:

`Aws.lookup(an_item_id)`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to require the gem if you need its functionality in your code.
2. You can only include a module, but `Amazon::Ecs` is [a class](https://github.com/jugend/amazon-ecs/blob/master/lib/amazon/ecs.rb). Instead, you can do this:

   ```
   def lookup( ... )
     Amazon::Ecs.instance_eval do
       item_lookup( ... )
     end
   end
   ```

   However, that is actually stinkier, IMO, than what you have. You can `include Amazon` if you really want to mess up your namespace and just use `Ecs.item_lookup`. What I would do, however, is:

   ```
   E = Amazon::Ecs
   def lookup( ... )
     E.item_lookup( ... )
   end
   ```
3. If you only need namespaced methods, and no state or settings preserved for different instances, use a module:

   ```
   module Aws
     E = Amazon::Ecs
     def self.lookup( ... )
       E.item_lookup
     end
   end
   Aws.lookup( ... )
   ```